# Listening to clipboard in a service in android

Tags: android

I want to listen to clipboard and if any thing copied , so i get it and process it.so I wrote a service for it.but it seems that android system killing my service process after a while that no word copy to clipboard.what I have to do that my service keep running?

```
public class Service_clipboard extends Service {


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mPrimaryChangeListener = new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {

                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

                DoSomeThing(clipboard.getText().toString());
            }
        };

        ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(mPrimaryChangeListener);

        return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Service#startForeground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)), it will make system not killing your service unless it needs memory badly.
The tradeoff is, you are required to post a notification to notify user that your app is running all the time.

Comment: Should not be using a service to listen for clipboard changes. A huge drain on the battery.